# Get HTML input form variable stored as an array as javascript variables

Tags: javascript

How do I get the value of an HTML input form that is stored as an array into a javascript variable:

HTML of input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="subject[0]" 
id="contact_subject" value="test message" />
```

...

```
<input name="contact" value="Send" type="submit" 
onkeypress="return validateMessage(0); false" 
onclick="return validateMessage(0); false"/>
```

My javascript attempt:

```
function validateMessage(counter){
var subject = document.forms["Contact"]["subject["+counter+"]"].value;
```

and also tried:

```
var subject = document.forms["Contact"]["subject"][counter].value;
```

subject is null on both attempts.

Comment: The example you've given is PHP, not strictly HTML. Can you change your example to show what's actually being sent to the browser?

Comment: Sure.  the php is just from a for loop that creates the array of the input fields.

Comment: Just post the actual html that the client gets please. Get rid of the php code because it is not relevant to the JavaScript question and only serves to obfuscate your question.

Comment: The first way you tried works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/JDrdK/1/ - it's not the _best_ way to do it necessarily, but it works... Note that you don't need an `onkeypress` handler on a button, because "pressing" the button with the spacebar or enter key will still trigger the `onclick` event. Note also that if that input is created in a loop you're creating invalid html because `id` needs to be unique (`name` _can_ be unique but doesn't have to be).

Comment: @nnnnnn i bet OP used id

Comment: also... **suggestion** use relative traverse and... **USE `onsubmit` EVENT** not `onclick` on the submit button.

Comment: it was in fact an `id` issue not allowing the function to throw a 'false'